# Issue when I define the CRS of raster files on R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

When I tried to define the CRS of my raster layers env :

```
crs(env) <- CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs ")
```

I got this error:

```
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid in CRS definition
```

Knowing that I'm using R 4.0.3 on Mac, and I didn't have this issue on the previous versions. Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Comment: I tried your projection and didn't run an error in my machine, do you have gdal, proj and geos installed?

Comment: I have "rgdal", "geos" and "proj4" libraries installed and I keep having the same problem. For the library "PROJ" when I try to install it it shows this message: PROJ is currently non-operational since version 0.4.0.

Comment: I didn't have this problem in the previous R versions.

Comment: This is a non-error, just a byproduct of the move to WKT projection definitions. You can suppress many of the related errors by putting `options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none")` in your Rprofile.site startup file or issuing it before adding any packages.